# how can i make the li inside the two div aligned

Tags: html, css

How can I make the two columns `li` to start at the same line. I want the `li` in the two columns to be aligned.

To make it more clear, I want it so when the first `li` start in column number 1 the `li` in column number to to start.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="width: 40%;">
    <ol>
      <li>With so many seniors and so many seniors and friends with special needs unable to leave their homes</li>
      <li>are we prioritize the health and safety of both clients and workers. COVID-19 is a serious health threat an</li>
      <li>ell as those who need assistance with the instrumental activities of daily living (such as preparing meals), have a number of options. Some seniors living</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="width: 40%;">
    <ol>
      <li>With so manth special needs unable to leave their homes</li>
      <li>during COVID-19, we have decided to offer</li>
      <li>While the coronavirus outbreak poses health risks for everyone, officia</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use table `td` or use javascript to realign.

Comment: @Rafee how can i use td with ol li?

Comment: Instead of using `ul li`. Just use `table`.

Comment: @Rafee I want to use ol for the numbering

Comment: Just add the numbering from server side if any or else add numbering using javascript. https://jsfiddle.net/24zdnxfu/

Comment: @Rafee you can add your comment in an answer so i can correct it

Answer (score 1):

To get the items aligned in a row I think you'll have to alter the HTML structure - removing the ordered list and replacing with plain divs and putting the two items that are to be on one row next to each other. This is so the system can calculate how much space it needs to reserve vertically to fit them in.

Using a CSS counter we can keep track of which row we are in and put that number out - so making it look as though we have two ordered lists side by side.

This snippet is a plain CSS method. Obviously you'll want to adapt things like padding for your own requirements.

```css
.lists {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: rowcounter;
}
.lists div {
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  flex: 40%;
}

.lists div:nth-child(odd) {
  counter-increment: rowcounter;
}
  
.lists div::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  content: counter(rowcounter) "."; 
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
      <div>With so many seniors and so many seniors and friends with special needs unable to leave their homes</div>
      <div>With so manth special needs unable to leave their homes</div>
      <div>are we prioritize the health and safety of both clients and workers. COVID-19 is a serious health threat an</div>
      <div>during COVID-19, we have decided to offer</div>
      <div>ell as those who need assistance with the instrumental activities of daily living (such as preparing meals), have a number of options. Some seniors living</div>
      <div>While the coronavirus outbreak poses health risks for everyone, officia</div>
</div>
```

Caveat: there may of course be an accessibility concern, if it is important that the two lists are actually structured as lists for example for screen readers.